# Find difference between old text file and updated one

Tags: php, cygwin, text-files, diff

I have tow files which I want to compare. The first file contains a list of x values. The second file contains a new x values, and may not contains some of first file x values. I want to compare them.

I want to compare the second file with the first file. **(Second file is an updated copy of the first file).**

- If there some x values deleted from the first "not included in the second file" , I don't want it to be in the third file.
- If there some x values added to the first "included in second
  file" , I  want it to be in the third file.

  - If some x values are same in the first and second file , I  want it to be in the third file.

I try Cygwin `diff` command. It find the difference between files. But,  can't use it in this case.

Any command can help me? I want to write it in PHP file.

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason you can't use the `diff` command, and if you can't use it why did you tag your question with `cygwin` ?

Comment: I can't use it because it will generate a new file with some of x values that are in 1st but not in 2nd! which is "deleted" in my case. I don't want to search against deleted items. I think cygwin may have such command.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/68684/how-can-i-get-diff-to-show-only-added-and-deleted-lines-if-diff-cant-do-it-wh may help

Comment: Also http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm also has similar methods.